# Install Alfa AWUS036NHA driver on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, wireless, 18.04

Output of  `lshw -C network`:

```
description: Ethernet interface
product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
```

This is my existing built-in wireless adapter.

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1871:0306 Aveo Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1c4f:0048 SiGma Micro 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

How do I use a USB wireless adapter Alfa AWUS036NHA instead?

How do I install the needed drivers for Ubuntu 18.04 to use the USB adapter for wireless communication?

Comment: Please edit your question to inclide the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` As you can see the built-in Realtek is ethernet, not wireless. Welcome ro Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the RTL8188FU driver, the steps are:

```
git clone https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu.git
cd rtl8188fu
make 
sudo make install
```

In case you encounter the following error:

```
$ sudo make install
install -p -m 644 .ko  /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
install: cannot stat '.ko': No such file or directory
Makefile:481: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Do:

```
sudo apt install libelf-dev
```

Then:

```
cd rtl8188fu
make clean
cd
sudo dkms add ./rtl8188fu
sudo dkms install rtl8188fu/1.0
```

Then reboot and test the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone doing this on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and having issues with the commands above, try this:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git dkms linux-headers-generic
git clone https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu
sudo dkms add ./rtl8188fu
sudo dkms build rtl8188fu/1.0
sudo dkms install rtl8188fu/1.0
sudo cp ./rtl8188fu/firmware/rtl8188fufw.bin /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/
```

See the page here for more info: https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu

Also beware of Laptop-Tools power management. You may have to add your Wi-Fi device to the pm blacklist.